# Is it possible to provide an externally accessible property to a .NET compiled exe?

Tags: .net, interface, runtime

I know how to create a .net dll such that I can "late bind" (or at least bind via a shared interface) by using LoadFrom and passing a .dll file name. Is there a way to do this opening a .exe so that I can call a method on the interface to pull some run-time configuration information from the .exe from an external system ? So like the application properties such as the file version etc., by dynamic at run-time. I want to pull the data rather than have the .exe push the data somewhere. And I cannot lift the code base into a dll and have a wrapper .exe due to environment compliance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get file versions fairly easily by using System.Diagnostics.  You may need to add a reference to it in your project or import it at the top of your class, but then you can do this.

```
    Dim verSql As FileVersionInfo
    Dim verFrms As FileVersionInfo
    Dim verUsers As FileVersionInfo
    Dim veredit As FileVersionInfo

verSql = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("MySQL.Data.dll")
verFrms = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("StdForms.dll")
verUsers = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("users.dll")
veredit = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("Editor.dll")
```

I use a similar version to the above code to show the version numbers of external DLL files in a project I have written at home.